# ¿Por qué se traduce 'derecho' como 'left' en este cuento?

Tags: traducción, inglés

Leo el cuento 'El Capitán Descalzo' de Norberto Fuentes en el [Penguin Parallel Text Series](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Spanish-Short-Stories-Hispanicos-Parallel/dp/0140033785). La traducción al inglés es de Vicky Ortiz.

La oración

> –Me persiguen – repitió el hombre, que sostenía un Garand y sobre la
> cadera **derecha** le pendía una pistolera.

ha sido traducido así

> 'They're after me,' repeated the man, who was holding a Garand rifle
> and had a holster on his **left** hip.

¿Por qué ha cambiado la traductora la cadera de derecha a izquierda?

Comment: It's a translation error. Very simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se puede decir que la labor realizada por Vicky Ortiz como traductora en la interpretación al inglés que hace del cuento "***El Capitán Descalzo***" de Norberto Fuentes da muestras de su talento y profesionalidad ya que existen detalles curiosos y este es uno de ellos.

Normalmente cuando se lleva una obra a otra lengua se busca un equilibrio para adaptar el lenguaje original a una cultura en muchos casos diferente. Así en la narración del trabajo se interpretan y amoldan por una parte, las características más visible y complicadas del idioma como es el lenguaje intraducible que recae en expresiones, refranes, dichos... de otra parte se continua con los aspectos menos visibles como son costumbres sociales, culturales, económicas... que igualmente tratan de ser explicadas teniendo en cuenta la visión de la lengua a la que se traduce, respetando algunos detalles propios que suelen pasar inadvertidos y que simplemente hacen referencia a ellos para conseguir una mejor comprensión lectora de los individuos que componen el conjunto de esa sociedad, en este caso la comunidad inglesa.

A este respecto, se trata específicamente de una **cuestión militar** sobre **donde llevar la funda o pistolera si en el lado derecho o en el izquierdo**. En este sentido hay que hacer notar que en el mundo inglés se capta mejor y es más normal percibir que la pistolera se encuentre en el lado izquierdo y no en el derecho ya que esto facilita el desenfunde y utilización del arma, pues tradicionalmente el ejercito inglés de forma especial, aunque también en otros, la localización de la funda o pistolera del arma se encontraba en ese lado izquierdo y no en el derecho.

---

Para ampliar la respuesta puede ver un video en inglés donde se muestra el uso del arma en el lado izquierdo y sus ventajas.

*Why did the British and other Euro Armies typically wear holsters on the left?*

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-NzgFGWJDw

---

**P.D.** *Para intentar aclarar un poco más, es como si en una traducción de una obra en inglés al español simplemente dice* "***iba conduciendo por el lado derecho de la calzada***", *cuando en el original inglés aparece como izquierdo, ya que es su costumbre original, pero para facilitarnos a nosotros el encuadre general de la lectura lo han interpretado como "derecho"*.

*Incluso en los títulos de muchas películas, la interpretación y el nombre cambia del inglés al español con la intención de que el nuevo título en español sea mejor asimilado por la comunidad, aunque no siempre lo consiguen*.

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo por una parte, pero en desacuerdo por otra. Este tipo de disonancia respecto al original debe acompañarse de una nota del traductor, para evitar precisamente la duda que pone en evidencia esta pregunta. Además, la decisión implícita del  traductor es de ajustar el cuento al lector, y no el lector al cuento. Creo que esa decisión le pertenece al lector y está ausente en el relato original.

Comment: ¡Completamente de acuerdo!